# I'm trying to use tkinter on python in sublime text on ubuntu but i keep getting a error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tkinter, sublimetext

So i'm trying to import tkinter in sublime text configured to python3.8 but i keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Can anyone help me because I really want to get back on working with school projects

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing tkinter? If you do have the import, it probably needs to be installed:sudo apt-get install python3-tk

Otherwise, post your code.

Comment: The code i used was just `import tkinter` and i have tried that command several times and it doesn't work

Comment: The `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` command in the terminal

Comment: Well this is your issue. Search stackoverflow or open a new question (tkinter install error) with the command you typed and the error you received.

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter
```

and if not installed :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```